# How to handle multiple-state domain object?

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, domain-driven-design

Let's take an example of `Order`.

An order can have the state `new`, `canceled`, `shipped`, or `processing`.

- The new order can be processed.
- The new order can be canceled.
- The processing order can be shipped.
- The processing order can be canceled.
- The canceled order cannot be processed, shipped, or new.
- The shipped order cannot be canceled, processed, or new.

I have 2 approaches to solve this problem.

---

### 1. Throws error if the state change is invalid

```
class Order {
  private state: string;

  ship() {
    if (this.state !== "processing") {
      throw new Error("Cannot ship an order that is not processing");
    }
    this.state = "shipped";
  }
}
```

This approach does the job. It blocks invalid state changes and throws error to fail fast.

I don't like this approach. It throws a lot of errors and does not tell the client how to use the domain object correctly. The clients can call the `ship` method whenever they want and they have to read the implementations to know how to use the domain object correctly.

Then I have the second approach.

### 2. Every state should have its class

```
class ProcessingOrder {
  readonly state = "processing";

  ship(): ShippedOrder {
    return new ShippedOrder();
  }
}

class ShippedOrder {
  readonly state = "shipped";
}
```

This approach blocks the invalid state changes by providing only the valid behavior. It teaches the client how to work with the object and minimize possible errors.

The thing I don't like about this approach is the method has to return another object. This violates the concept of Entity in Domain-Driven Design. The same entity is created multiple times because of the state change.

---

Which approach should I use?

If you don't use any of my approaches, could you tell me your approach?

Comment: Just curious. Does DDD allow entities belonging to an aggregate to be changed out of the aggregate? Do they even have logic like the one involving a machine state? If not, the argument "clients can call/change the state any time anywhere is no longer valid. On the other hand wouldn't "Shipping" be a use case /op operating at much higher level of abstraction than the one entities live in?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement state machine pattern on aggregate root](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/364910/how-to-implement-state-machine-pattern-on-aggregate-root)

Comment: Why does it "violate the concept of Entity in Domain-Driven Design"?

Comment: My experience: there isn't a good approach here, just lots of disappointing ones with different tradeoffs.

Comment: @Laiv DDD only allows entities to be changed inside of the aggregate using aggregate root. In this example `Order` is the aggregate root itself. The state change is allowed.

Comment: @guillaume31 In Domain-Driven Design, you want to keep the entity object as long as possible, while we can always recreate a new Value Object. Using the 2nd approach creates a new entity object with the same id. Since the entity is defined by its id, they are the same object. In other words, we are re-creating the entity object.

Comment: I've never heard of "you want to keep the entity object as long as possible" from an OO perspective. It's even a typical thing to implement custom comparison to determine if one entity object is the same as another...

Comment: @guillaume31 Wow. I have had the wrong understanding of it until now. Thanks for pointing that out :)
The second approach is the better solution. Do you think so?

Comment: Go with option 1. Option 2 is a giant headache. The idea that you need to protect *clients* from using your objects in a way that produces an error is... going to take you down a really rough road. Your domain is to protect your invariants, not the client (which is just you right?).